# define a S4 method if there is already a function with the same name

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

I have a function **myFunction** and I need to create a S4 method with the same name (do not ask me why).
I would like to keep the old functionality of **myFunction**.

Is there a way to keep my old function?

I would rather not set a generic for this old function as the signature may be very different...

Comment: basically I want to know if it is a case of **conflict** (That I have to solve by deleting one of the two), or if S4 system is designed to deal with that. I don't want to trick the system.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a way to keep your old function. And unless you want both the S3 and S4 functions to accept the same number of arguments of the same classes, it's not even complicated to do.

```
# Create an S3 function named "myFun"
myFun <- function(x) cat(x, "\n")

# Create an S4 function named "myFun", dispatched when myFun() is called with 
# a single numeric argument
setMethod("myFun", signature=signature(x="numeric"), function(x) rnorm(x))

# When called with a numeric argument, the S4 function is dispatched
myFun(6)
# [1]  0.3502462 -1.3327865 -0.9338347 -0.7718385  0.7593676  0.3961752

# When called with any other class of argument, the S3 function is dispatched
myFun("hello")
# hello
```

If you *do* want the S4 function to take the same type of argument as the S3 function, you'll need to do something like the following, setting the class of the argument so that R has some way of divining which of the two functions you are intending it to use:

```
setMethod("myFun", signature=signature(x="greeting"), 
          function(x) cat(x, x, x, "\n"))

# Create an object of class "greeting" that will dispatch the just-created 
# S4 function
XX <- "hello"
class(XX) <- "greeting"
myFun(XX)
# hello hello hello 

# A supplied argument of class "character" still dispatches the S3 function
myFun("hello")
# hello
```

Comment: What happens if the old myFun has no argument?

Comment: Do you mean no formal argument (like, e.g. `search()`), or no default argument?  In neither case should it make an important difference. (I will, though, slightly edit my answer to remove the irrelevant default argument I gave to the S3 function.)

Comment: Yes I mean no formal argument. It does make a difference because when setting the new method, R uses the old myFun as generic for this method. And I get an error message stating that dispatching cannot be done using this function.
From what I understand now, such a function may not be a proper candidate to be a generic and I am not sure it is not a good practice to use methods that have this name. I think it is a case of conflict. Do you have any idea how usually this issue is tackled?

Comment: @ Josh: Can you try  

    myFun2 <- function() cat("TEST", "\n"); setMethod("myFun2", signature=signature(x="numeric"), function(x) rnorm(x))

Comment: You're right, of course. It does make a difference, and I misstated above, thinking that you were focused on the default argument.

Comment: Based on last comment, I see your problem, and am equally stumped about what to do in a case like that.

Comment: Um, I'm a bit confused.  So the trick is that you don't set a generic?  And if you were to set a generic, it would mask the S3 function?

Comment: @cboettig There's not really any trick here. `setMethod()` goes ahead and sets a generic if one doesn't already exist (and actually gives you a little note that it's doing so, as can be seen when running the code above). For more, see paragraph four of the `"Basic Usage"` section of [**`?setGeneric`**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/methods/html/setGeneric.html)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien weird, I see the note in "Basic Usage" that it calls that, but if I execute setMethod() when no function of that name or setGeneric has been called I just get an error `no existing definition for function ‘myFun’`

Comment: @cboettig -- You have to have previously defined an S3 function called `myFun`. (i.e. you need to run the first line of code I provided before running the second.)